# Replacing string in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, xhtml, replace, innerhtml

So, this is a fairly simple thing I'm trying to accomplish (javascript), but it's taking me ages and it still does not work. I'm trying to replace certain words (that are within a pre tag). For example, the word `"static"` should be replaced by 
`"<span class="keyword">static</span>"`. I'm using XHTML strict.

My approach is like this:

```
for (var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++)
    {
        codeBlock.innerHTML = codeBlock.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(keywords[j], "g"), "<span class=\"keyword\">" + keywords[j] + "</span>");
    }
```

codeBlock is the pre element, keywords is an array that contains all the words I would like to replace.

I've tried so many ways, but I'm stuck with error messages like these.

Firefox:

> [Exception... "An invalid or illegal string was specified"  code: "12" nsresult: "0x8053000c (NS_ERROR_DOM_SYNTAX_ERR)"  location: "file:///C:/.../scripts.js Line: 33"]

Chrome:

> Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11

I'm guessing it has something to do with the html tags (I've tried using %lt; and %gt; instead), because I know that this does work:

> codeBlock.innerHTML =
>   codeBlock.innerHTML.replace(new
>   RegExp(keywords[j], "g"), "test");

Thanks you for your time, 
Jacco

Comment: I think you cannot use (set) `innerHTML` with XHTML (strict).

Comment: any chance you can post a complete html and javascript example that exhibits this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap your code in CDATA

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
for (var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++)
    {
        codeBlock.innerHTML = codeBlock.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(keywords[j], "g"), "<span class=\"keyword\">" + keywords[j] + "</span>");
    }
 //]]>
</script>
```

[Properly Using CSS and JavaScript in XHTML Documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/properly_using_css_and_javascript_in_xhtml_documents#Using_CDATA_Instead_of_Comments)

This way your code will not be parsed for XHTML validity.

---

Your current code works fine for me at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Y92AE/

Comment: Thanks, but my script is in a seperate .js file though. It doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @Jacco, what browser (*and version*) do you use ?

Comment: Google Chrome 11.0.696.65
Firefox 4.0.1

Comment: Oh! I just noticed that I've got these words like "class" in my array, which will definitely not help the class attribute in the span tags. Thanks for your help.