# Find and remove text in div with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Im having trouble trying to find a text in a jquery modal and removing it.

```
<div id="layer-303" class="layer">
    <div id="boton_cerrar" class="cerrar" onclick="javascript:void(cerrarLayer('layer-303'));">cerrar</div>
        <div class="cnt_sin_pst">
            <div id="id_pst_layer_0" class="pst_contenido">
                <div class="mod mod100">
                    '','canal'=&gt;'null','seccion'=&gt;'null','canal_name'=&gt;'internet2015'); ?&gt;<div class="pill">
                    <div class="contentweb">
```

The text inside the div `mod mod100` is what im trying to find and remove. I have used the following but it removes all the html inside the modal.

```
$(".layer:contains(''','canal'=&gt;'null','seccion'=&gt;'null','canal_name'=&gt;'internet2015'); ?&gt;')").remove()
```

The exact text which appears when opening the modal is: **'','canal'=>'null','seccion'=>'null','canal_name'=>'internet2015'); ?>**

Comment: you can just use `innerHTML` and a simple string [`replace` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955823/replacing-string-in-innerhtml)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace innerHTML of a div using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309452/how-to-replace-innerhtml-of-a-div-using-jquery)

Comment: @vsync that would change everything inside my modal to whatever I replace it with

Comment: `node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace('x','y')`

Comment: Could you help me out? I cant seem to figure it out: https://jsfiddle.net/u22k3eqj/24/

Comment: @vsync can u check the fiddle i created to solve my issue?

Comment: what exactly am I supposed to do in the fiddle? you left no instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to preserve the remaining content - you want to simply remove that text (assumng it is always that content - the best solution would be to find the reason why its being inserted and remove that cause - but what you can do is simply replace the offending text string without destroying other html content.

```js
var content  = $('.mod.mod100').html();
    
    var str = "'','canal'=&gt;'null','seccion'=&gt;'null','canal_name'=&gt;'internet2015'); ?&gt;";
    
    $('.mod.mod100').html(content.replace(str, ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="layer-303" class="layer">
    <div id="boton_cerrar" class="cerrar" onclick="javascript:void(cerrarLayer('layer-303'));">cerrar</div>
         <div class="cnt_sin_pst">
            <div id="id_pst_layer_0" class="pst_contenido">
                <div class="mod mod100">
 '','canal'=&gt;'null','seccion'=&gt;'null','canal_name'=&gt;'internet2015'); ?&gt;<div class="pill">
                    <div class="contentweb">
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: what if I have the same text twice in my modal in different divs? It only removes the first one but not the second one. https://jsfiddle.net/u22k3eqj/32/

Comment: @PLATANIUM in that case you need to specify all that divs some how.
`$('.mod.mod100').html(content.replace(str, ''));` this code is touches all divs with `class="mod mod100"`
Here's example http://jsfiddle.net/smollet92/q2w0zgbv/